# Mutual Fund NAV in 401k

Tags: mutual-funds

Why is the NAV price of my the Mutual Fund in my 401k account approximately TWICE the price vs. checking the NAV of the Mutual Fund online ?

Comment: Probably a different class (e.g. Class A or Class C). What are the _full_ names and tickers of each fund?

Comment: This might be a question for your hr person or plan administrator.